# Issue in getting file path

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I am using download manager in kotlin - android.
Downloded a file successfully as below :

```
fun downloadFirmwareFile(baseActivity: Context, url: String?, title: String?): Long {
    val direct = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/firmware")

    if (!direct.exists()) {
        direct.mkdirs()
    }
    val extension = url?.substring(url.lastIndexOf("."))
    val downloadReference: Long
    var dm: DownloadManager = baseActivity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val uri = Uri.parse(url)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)

    var subPath = "bin" + System.currentTimeMillis() + extension
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,
            subPath)

    Log.e("File path >> ", Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + subPath)

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    request.setTitle(title)
    Toast.makeText(baseActivity, "start Downloading..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    downloadReference = dm?.enqueue(request) ?: 0


    downloadFirmwareLiveData.postValue("")

    var file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), subPath)
    if (file.exists()) {
        Log.e("path >>>>>>>>>", "path >>>>>>>>>" + file.absolutePath)
    }else{
        Log.e("path >>>>>>>>>", "path >>>>>>>>> File not exists")
    }
    return downloadReference
}
```

Here, you can see I am trying to get the file path which is downloaded as below :

```
var file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), subPath)
if (file.exists()) {
    Log.e("path >>>>>>>>>", "path >>>>>>>>>" + file.absolutePath)
}else{
    Log.e("path >>>>>>>>>", "path >>>>>>>>> File not exists")
}
```

But it gives me : path >>>>>>>>> File not exists

What might be the issue ? Please guide.

Comment: The file is not downloaded yet. You are too early with that code.

Comment: I think so, How can I resolve this?

Comment: Register a broadcast receiver for ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE. (Or however it is called). Then you will get an uri from the download manager for the downloaded file. All pretty standard stuff. You will find code all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own `URI` and use it for downloading content then you might use below code.

First add `provider` in `manifest.xml` file. Like

```
       <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<paths>
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
```

You could now create your own `URI` and let `download manager` to save your file content inside that. Look below code:

```
        fun downloadFirmwareFile(baseActivity: Context, url: String?, title: String?,saveFileUri: Uri): Long {
        
        val downloadReference: Long
        val dm: DownloadManager
        dm = baseActivity.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)

        // Here uri is passed and image will be downloaded inside this file--
        request.setDestinationUri(saveFileUri)
/*    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,
            "bin" + System.currentTimeMillis() + extension)*/
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        request.setTitle(title)
        Toast.makeText(baseActivity, "start Downloading..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        downloadReference = dm.enqueue(request) ?: 0

        return downloadReference
    }
```

And you have to create `URI` before start downloading. Like below:

```
        downlodNowBtn.setOnClickListener {
        context?.let {
            createImageFile().let { downloadFile ->
                try {
                    // storing URI in a variable, so that it could be used further if required......
                    downloadedFileUri = Uri.fromFile(downloadFile)
                    Log.d("tisha==>>","File Uri= ${}")
                    // replace with your desired url----------------------------
                    downloadFirmwareFile(it,"https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png","My photo", Uri.fromFile(downloadFile))
                }catch (e: java.lang.Exception){
                    Log.d("tisha==>>"," ${e.localizedMessage}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    // Create an image file name
   // val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())
    val storageDir: File? = requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    return File(storageDir,"test.jpg")
}
```

Now you can read your file from previously stored `URI`. Like:

```
  val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(downloadedFileUri?.let { it1 -> context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(it1) })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to register `BroadcastReceiver` to know the status of downloading completed or not. Like:

```
    var onComplete: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(ctxt: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d("TAG==>>","Download completed")
        val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), subFilePath)
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.d("TAG==>>", "path >>>>>>>>>" + file.absolutePath)
        }else{
            Log.d("TAG==>>", "path >>>>>>>>> File not exists")
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `onCreate()` register `broadCastReceiver` like `registerReceiver(onComplete, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))`

Inside `onDestroy()` unregister `broadCastReceiver` like

```
 override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    unregisterReceiver(onComplete)
}
```